# Recursively calculate product weights in product tree

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm developing a software for Consumer price index calculation and one step of all calculation is to calculate product weights in product category. This should be done in SQL server side. I have MS SQL Server 2008.
The product catalog are stored in a tree:

```
|id|ProductCode|ParentId|Weight|
--------------------------------
|1 |01         |NULL    |0     |
|2 |01.1       | 1      |0     |
|3 |01.1.1     | 2      |0     |
|4 |01.1.1.101 | 3      |0.14  |
|5 |01.1.1.102 | 3      |0.1   |
|6 |01.1.1.103 | 3      |0.25  |
|7 |01.1.1.104 | 3      |0.02  |
|8 |01.1.2     | 2      |0     |
|9 |01.1.2.201 | 8      |0.05  |
|10|01.1.2.202 | 8      |0.3   |
--------------------------------
```

It is simplified structure of my table, so i need to calculate weights for categories.

For example:

- weight for category '01.1.1' = sum of product weight 01.1.1.101 + 01.1.1.102 + 01.1.1.103 + 01.1.1.104 =0.51
- for category '01.1.2' = sum of 01.1.2.201 + 01.1.2.201 = 0.35
- for category  01.1 = sum of 01.1.1 +01.1.2 =0.51 +0.35 = 0.86
- for category 01 = sum of 01.1 + 01.2 (not showed in my example)

And my problem actually  is, I can't calculate weights of parent categories.

Maybe someone can help me to solve my problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Joakim's answer does not give the correct result.

Perhaps this will work:

```
-- Use a safe database
use tempdb

if object_id('Products') is not null drop table Products

create table Products (
    id int,
    ProductCode varchar(100),
    ParentId int,
    Weight float
)

-- Original sample data
insert into Products (id,ProductCode, ParentId, Weight)
SELECT 1 ,'01',        NULL    ,'0'      UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ,'01.1'       , '1'      ,'0'      UNION ALL
SELECT '3 ','01.1.1',' 2      ','0     ' UNION ALL
SELECT '4 ','01.1.1.101',' 3      ','0.14  ' UNION ALL
SELECT '5 ','01.1.1.102',' 3      ','0.1   ' UNION ALL
SELECT '6 ','01.1.1.103',' 3      ','0.25  ' UNION ALL
SELECT '7 ','01.1.1.104',' 3      ','0.02  ' UNION ALL
SELECT '8 ','01.1.2',' 2      ','0     ' UNION ALL
SELECT '9 ','01.1.2.201',' 8      ','0.05  ' UNION ALL
SELECT '10','01.1.2.202',' 8      ','0.3   ' 

-- Extra test data
insert into Products (id,ProductCode, ParentId, Weight)
SELECT 11 ,'01.2',        1    ,'1.1'      

-- Calculate result
select b.ProductCode, SUM(a.Weight) as WeightSum
from Products a
join Products b on b.ProductCode = left(a.ProductCode, len(b.ProductCode))  and len(b.ProductCode) < len(a.ProductCode)
group by b.ProductCode
```

Result:

```
ProductCode WeightSum
01  1,96
01.1    0,86
01.1.1  0,51
01.1.2  0,35
```

Answer (score 1):

this might be done by a recursive approach trailing along the chain of `ParentId`. In this case I'd start at a leaf-node (no rows use this id as parent-id) and compute the sum while moving up the chain.

But - as there is existing a *path*, the `ProductCode`, it might be easier to use an approach like this:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(id INT, ProductCode VARCHAR(100),ParentId INT,[Weight] DECIMAL(10,4));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 (1,'01'         ,NULL,0     )
,(2,'01.1'       ,1   ,0     )
,(3,'01.1.1'     ,2   ,0     )
,(4,'01.1.1.101' ,3   ,0.14  )
,(5,'01.1.1.102' ,3   ,0.1   )
,(6,'01.1.1.103' ,3   ,0.25  )
,(7,'01.1.1.104' ,3   ,0.02  )
,(8,'01.1.2'     ,2   ,0     )
,(9,'01.1.2.201' ,8   ,0.05  )
,(10,'01.1.2.202',8   ,0.3   );

DECLARE @depth INT=3;

SELECT groupCode
      ,*
FROM @mockup 
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(ProductCode,'.','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
                  .query(N'for $frgmt in /x[position()<=sql:variable("@depth")]/text() 
                           return <y>{concat(".",$frgmt)}</y>')
                  .value('substring(.,2,1000)','nvarchar(max)')) A(groupCode);
```

This allows you to define a *depth* and proceed form there.

You might create a cte, group it to get your distinct codes and sum the up

```
DECLARE @depth INT=3;

WITH cte As
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @mockup 
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(ProductCode,'.','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
                      .query(N'for $frgmt in /x[position()<=sql:variable("@depth")]/text() 
                               return <y>{concat(".",$frgmt)}</y>')
                      .value('substring(.,2,1000)','nvarchar(max)')) A(groupCode)
)
SELECT groupCode
      ,(SELECT SUM(cte2.[Weight]) FROM cte cte2 WHERE cte2.groupCode LIKE cte.groupCode + '%')
FROM cte
GROUP BY groupCode
```

The result

```
groupCode   SumOfWeigth
01          0.8600
01.1        0.8600
01.1.1      0.5100
01.1.2      0.3500
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `ProductCode` contains the hierarchy, you can do this without recursion.  Here is a method using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select p.*, (case when p.weight = 0 then pchild.weight else p.weight end) as weight
from products p outer apply
     (select sum(pchild.weight) as weight
      from products pchild
      where p.weight = 0 and
            pchild.productCode like p.productCode  + '.%'
     ) pchild;
```

And a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=21f540e3bdb2b6e8703702d09e991f93).

You can actually simplify the `SELECT` to:

```
select p.*, coalesce(pchild.weight, p.weight) as weight
```